# Want to understand the meaning of certain lines of code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I came across that classic algorithm problem, Longest Palindrome Substring, in which one has to extract the longest palindromic substring from a given string, I saw this very simple brute force solution, but I don't think I fully understand its syntax.

```
def longestPalindrome( s):
    longest = “”
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(len(s),i,-1):
            if s[i:j] == s[i:j][::-1]:
                if len(longest) < len(s[i:j]):
                    longest = s[i:j]
    return longest
```

From what I could gather, it checks if all the substrings in a given string are palindromes by comparing them in size and finding the largest one. My question regards specific lines, in which I want to understand what is actually happening.

```
        for j in range(len(s),i,-1):
            if s[i:j] == s[i:j][::-1]:
                if len(longest) < len(s[i:j]):
                    longest = s[i:j]
```

In the first line, I do understand that there is an iteration going on in the length of the main string, but I don't get the ",i,-1)" part. What does this mean?
In the "if len(longest) < len(s[i:j]):" line, I just don't understand the comparison itself. I mean, a variable was created to store the longest palindrome substring, but why should it be smaller than the length of the palindrome found?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Understanding someone else's code is not on-topic for Stack Overflow. The problem is that we don't know why you don't understand it already, and the site is not designed for talking back and forth with you. You should try a proper forum, such as https://reddit.com/r/learnpython.

Comment: print(range(start,stop,step) here I assume it’s range(max,min,-1) because you go from big to small number in -1 step try it out https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

Comment: Add the beginning longest is empty than assumes the first short palindrome subsequence and then goes up and longest is replaced only if longest is shorter than the new one given the palindrome if above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
1 for j in range(len(s), i, -1):
2     if s[i:j] == s[i:j][::-1]:
3         if len(longest) < len(s[i:j]):
4             longest = s[i:j]
```

#### Line 1:

Iterate over a `range` generator, from `len(s)` **down** to `i`, with stepsize `-1` (backwards)

#### Line 2:

- `s[i:j]`: Substring from character `i` up to character `j`
- `s[i:j][::-1]` Substring of substring with stepsize `-1` (backwards)

`s[i:j] == s[i:j][::-1]` compares the substring of `s` from `i` to `j` with the inverted (backwards) substring of `s` from `j` to `i`. This is the actual palindrome detection. The palindrome does **not** get save to a varaible

#### Lines 3 & 4:

(these get only executed if line 2 found a plindrome)
Check if the current longest Palindrome is shorter then the just found one, and if it is, write the new one into the `longest` variable

Comment: Thank you so very much for taking the time! Very didactic explanation, sometimes I get a bit stuck on details but it's because I want to understand what a code really does and how, not just grasp the general meaning. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I voted for  @Xtrem532 answer, but however needed to see it to visualize it better

```
def longestPalindrome( s):
    longest = ''
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(len(s),i,-1):
            pal = 'NO'
            # print(i,'   :  ',j)
            if s[i:j] == s[i:j][::-1]:
                pal ='YES'
                if len(longest) < len(s[i:j]):
                    longest = s[i:j]
            print('I :', i,' J :',j ,'  :  ',s[i:j], '    ',s[i:j][::-1], '    ', pal,'   ',longest)
    return longest

pippo = longestPalindrome('AATGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGACCC')

print('\n Longest Palindrome Substring : ', pippo)
```

here the output:

print is:

`print('I :', i,' J :',j ,'  :  ',s[i:j], '    ',s[i:j][::-1], '    ', pal,'   ',longest)`

pal is NO oe YES depending on if palindrome is found after it longest palindrom recorded

```
I : 0  J : 23   :   AATGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCTGATGCCTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 22   :   AATGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGACC      CCAGTGCTGATGCCTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 21   :   AATGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGAC      CAGTGCTGATGCCTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 20   :   AATGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGA      AGTGCTGATGCCTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 19   :   AATGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTG      GTGCTGATGCCTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 18   :   AATGTGGTCCGTAGTCGT      TGCTGATGCCTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 17   :   AATGTGGTCCGTAGTCG      GCTGATGCCTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 16   :   AATGTGGTCCGTAGTC      CTGATGCCTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 15   :   AATGTGGTCCGTAGT      TGATGCCTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 14   :   AATGTGGTCCGTAG      GATGCCTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 13   :   AATGTGGTCCGTA      ATGCCTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 12   :   AATGTGGTCCGT      TGCCTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 11   :   AATGTGGTCCG      GCCTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 10   :   AATGTGGTCC      CCTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 9   :   AATGTGGTC      CTGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 8   :   AATGTGGT      TGGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 7   :   AATGTGG      GGTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 6   :   AATGTG      GTGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 5   :   AATGT      TGTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 4   :   AATG      GTAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 3   :   AAT      TAA      NO     
I : 0  J : 2   :   AA      AA      YES     AA
I : 0  J : 1   :   A      A      YES     AA
I : 1  J : 23   :   ATGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCTGATGCCTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 22   :   ATGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGACC      CCAGTGCTGATGCCTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 21   :   ATGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGAC      CAGTGCTGATGCCTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 20   :   ATGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGA      AGTGCTGATGCCTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 19   :   ATGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTG      GTGCTGATGCCTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 18   :   ATGTGGTCCGTAGTCGT      TGCTGATGCCTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 17   :   ATGTGGTCCGTAGTCG      GCTGATGCCTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 16   :   ATGTGGTCCGTAGTC      CTGATGCCTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 15   :   ATGTGGTCCGTAGT      TGATGCCTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 14   :   ATGTGGTCCGTAG      GATGCCTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 13   :   ATGTGGTCCGTA      ATGCCTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 12   :   ATGTGGTCCGT      TGCCTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 11   :   ATGTGGTCCG      GCCTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 10   :   ATGTGGTCC      CCTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 9   :   ATGTGGTC      CTGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 8   :   ATGTGGT      TGGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 7   :   ATGTGG      GGTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 6   :   ATGTG      GTGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 5   :   ATGT      TGTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 4   :   ATG      GTA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 3   :   AT      TA      NO     AA
I : 1  J : 2   :   A      A      YES     AA
I : 2  J : 23   :   TGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCTGATGCCTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 22   :   TGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGACC      CCAGTGCTGATGCCTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 21   :   TGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGAC      CAGTGCTGATGCCTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 20   :   TGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGA      AGTGCTGATGCCTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 19   :   TGTGGTCCGTAGTCGTG      GTGCTGATGCCTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 18   :   TGTGGTCCGTAGTCGT      TGCTGATGCCTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 17   :   TGTGGTCCGTAGTCG      GCTGATGCCTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 16   :   TGTGGTCCGTAGTC      CTGATGCCTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 15   :   TGTGGTCCGTAGT      TGATGCCTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 14   :   TGTGGTCCGTAG      GATGCCTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 13   :   TGTGGTCCGTA      ATGCCTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 12   :   TGTGGTCCGT      TGCCTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 11   :   TGTGGTCCG      GCCTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 10   :   TGTGGTCC      CCTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 9   :   TGTGGTC      CTGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 8   :   TGTGGT      TGGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 7   :   TGTGG      GGTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 6   :   TGTG      GTGT      NO     AA
I : 2  J : 5   :   TGT      TGT      YES     TGT
I : 2  J : 4   :   TG      GT      NO     TGT
I : 2  J : 3   :   T      T      YES     TGT
I : 3  J : 23   :   GTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCTGATGCCTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 22   :   GTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGACC      CCAGTGCTGATGCCTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 21   :   GTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGAC      CAGTGCTGATGCCTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 20   :   GTGGTCCGTAGTCGTGA      AGTGCTGATGCCTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 19   :   GTGGTCCGTAGTCGTG      GTGCTGATGCCTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 18   :   GTGGTCCGTAGTCGT      TGCTGATGCCTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 17   :   GTGGTCCGTAGTCG      GCTGATGCCTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 16   :   GTGGTCCGTAGTC      CTGATGCCTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 15   :   GTGGTCCGTAGT      TGATGCCTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 14   :   GTGGTCCGTAG      GATGCCTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 13   :   GTGGTCCGTA      ATGCCTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 12   :   GTGGTCCGT      TGCCTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 11   :   GTGGTCCG      GCCTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 10   :   GTGGTCC      CCTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 9   :   GTGGTC      CTGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 8   :   GTGGT      TGGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 7   :   GTGG      GGTG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 6   :   GTG      GTG      YES     TGT
I : 3  J : 5   :   GT      TG      NO     TGT
I : 3  J : 4   :   G      G      YES     TGT
I : 4  J : 23   :   TGGTCCGTAGTCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCTGATGCCTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 22   :   TGGTCCGTAGTCGTGACC      CCAGTGCTGATGCCTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 21   :   TGGTCCGTAGTCGTGAC      CAGTGCTGATGCCTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 20   :   TGGTCCGTAGTCGTGA      AGTGCTGATGCCTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 19   :   TGGTCCGTAGTCGTG      GTGCTGATGCCTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 18   :   TGGTCCGTAGTCGT      TGCTGATGCCTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 17   :   TGGTCCGTAGTCG      GCTGATGCCTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 16   :   TGGTCCGTAGTC      CTGATGCCTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 15   :   TGGTCCGTAGT      TGATGCCTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 14   :   TGGTCCGTAG      GATGCCTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 13   :   TGGTCCGTA      ATGCCTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 12   :   TGGTCCGT      TGCCTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 11   :   TGGTCCG      GCCTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 10   :   TGGTCC      CCTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 9   :   TGGTC      CTGGT      NO     TGT
I : 4  J : 8   :   TGGT      TGGT      YES     TGGT
I : 4  J : 7   :   TGG      GGT      NO     TGGT
I : 4  J : 6   :   TG      GT      NO     TGGT
I : 4  J : 5   :   T      T      YES     TGGT
I : 5  J : 23   :   GGTCCGTAGTCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCTGATGCCTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 22   :   GGTCCGTAGTCGTGACC      CCAGTGCTGATGCCTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 21   :   GGTCCGTAGTCGTGAC      CAGTGCTGATGCCTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 20   :   GGTCCGTAGTCGTGA      AGTGCTGATGCCTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 19   :   GGTCCGTAGTCGTG      GTGCTGATGCCTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 18   :   GGTCCGTAGTCGT      TGCTGATGCCTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 17   :   GGTCCGTAGTCG      GCTGATGCCTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 16   :   GGTCCGTAGTC      CTGATGCCTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 15   :   GGTCCGTAGT      TGATGCCTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 14   :   GGTCCGTAG      GATGCCTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 13   :   GGTCCGTA      ATGCCTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 12   :   GGTCCGT      TGCCTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 11   :   GGTCCG      GCCTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 10   :   GGTCC      CCTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 9   :   GGTC      CTGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 8   :   GGT      TGG      NO     TGGT
I : 5  J : 7   :   GG      GG      YES     TGGT
I : 5  J : 6   :   G      G      YES     TGGT
I : 6  J : 23   :   GTCCGTAGTCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCTGATGCCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 22   :   GTCCGTAGTCGTGACC      CCAGTGCTGATGCCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 21   :   GTCCGTAGTCGTGAC      CAGTGCTGATGCCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 20   :   GTCCGTAGTCGTGA      AGTGCTGATGCCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 19   :   GTCCGTAGTCGTG      GTGCTGATGCCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 18   :   GTCCGTAGTCGT      TGCTGATGCCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 17   :   GTCCGTAGTCG      GCTGATGCCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 16   :   GTCCGTAGTC      CTGATGCCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 15   :   GTCCGTAGT      TGATGCCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 14   :   GTCCGTAG      GATGCCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 13   :   GTCCGTA      ATGCCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 12   :   GTCCGT      TGCCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 11   :   GTCCG      GCCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 10   :   GTCC      CCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 9   :   GTC      CTG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 8   :   GT      TG      NO     TGGT
I : 6  J : 7   :   G      G      YES     TGGT
I : 7  J : 23   :   TCCGTAGTCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCTGATGCCT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 22   :   TCCGTAGTCGTGACC      CCAGTGCTGATGCCT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 21   :   TCCGTAGTCGTGAC      CAGTGCTGATGCCT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 20   :   TCCGTAGTCGTGA      AGTGCTGATGCCT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 19   :   TCCGTAGTCGTG      GTGCTGATGCCT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 18   :   TCCGTAGTCGT      TGCTGATGCCT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 17   :   TCCGTAGTCG      GCTGATGCCT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 16   :   TCCGTAGTC      CTGATGCCT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 15   :   TCCGTAGT      TGATGCCT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 14   :   TCCGTAG      GATGCCT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 13   :   TCCGTA      ATGCCT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 12   :   TCCGT      TGCCT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 11   :   TCCG      GCCT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 10   :   TCC      CCT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 9   :   TC      CT      NO     TGGT
I : 7  J : 8   :   T      T      YES     TGGT
I : 8  J : 23   :   CCGTAGTCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCTGATGCC      NO     TGGT
I : 8  J : 22   :   CCGTAGTCGTGACC      CCAGTGCTGATGCC      NO     TGGT
I : 8  J : 21   :   CCGTAGTCGTGAC      CAGTGCTGATGCC      NO     TGGT
I : 8  J : 20   :   CCGTAGTCGTGA      AGTGCTGATGCC      NO     TGGT
I : 8  J : 19   :   CCGTAGTCGTG      GTGCTGATGCC      NO     TGGT
I : 8  J : 18   :   CCGTAGTCGT      TGCTGATGCC      NO     TGGT
I : 8  J : 17   :   CCGTAGTCG      GCTGATGCC      NO     TGGT
I : 8  J : 16   :   CCGTAGTC      CTGATGCC      NO     TGGT
I : 8  J : 15   :   CCGTAGT      TGATGCC      NO     TGGT
I : 8  J : 14   :   CCGTAG      GATGCC      NO     TGGT
I : 8  J : 13   :   CCGTA      ATGCC      NO     TGGT
I : 8  J : 12   :   CCGT      TGCC      NO     TGGT
I : 8  J : 11   :   CCG      GCC      NO     TGGT
I : 8  J : 10   :   CC      CC      YES     TGGT
I : 8  J : 9   :   C      C      YES     TGGT
I : 9  J : 23   :   CGTAGTCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCTGATGC      NO     TGGT
I : 9  J : 22   :   CGTAGTCGTGACC      CCAGTGCTGATGC      NO     TGGT
I : 9  J : 21   :   CGTAGTCGTGAC      CAGTGCTGATGC      NO     TGGT
I : 9  J : 20   :   CGTAGTCGTGA      AGTGCTGATGC      NO     TGGT
I : 9  J : 19   :   CGTAGTCGTG      GTGCTGATGC      NO     TGGT
I : 9  J : 18   :   CGTAGTCGT      TGCTGATGC      NO     TGGT
I : 9  J : 17   :   CGTAGTCG      GCTGATGC      NO     TGGT
I : 9  J : 16   :   CGTAGTC      CTGATGC      NO     TGGT
I : 9  J : 15   :   CGTAGT      TGATGC      NO     TGGT
I : 9  J : 14   :   CGTAG      GATGC      NO     TGGT
I : 9  J : 13   :   CGTA      ATGC      NO     TGGT
I : 9  J : 12   :   CGT      TGC      NO     TGGT
I : 9  J : 11   :   CG      GC      NO     TGGT
I : 9  J : 10   :   C      C      YES     TGGT
I : 10  J : 23   :   GTAGTCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCTGATG      NO     TGGT
I : 10  J : 22   :   GTAGTCGTGACC      CCAGTGCTGATG      NO     TGGT
I : 10  J : 21   :   GTAGTCGTGAC      CAGTGCTGATG      NO     TGGT
I : 10  J : 20   :   GTAGTCGTGA      AGTGCTGATG      NO     TGGT
I : 10  J : 19   :   GTAGTCGTG      GTGCTGATG      NO     TGGT
I : 10  J : 18   :   GTAGTCGT      TGCTGATG      NO     TGGT
I : 10  J : 17   :   GTAGTCG      GCTGATG      NO     TGGT
I : 10  J : 16   :   GTAGTC      CTGATG      NO     TGGT
I : 10  J : 15   :   GTAGT      TGATG      NO     TGGT
I : 10  J : 14   :   GTAG      GATG      NO     TGGT
I : 10  J : 13   :   GTA      ATG      NO     TGGT
I : 10  J : 12   :   GT      TG      NO     TGGT
I : 10  J : 11   :   G      G      YES     TGGT
I : 11  J : 23   :   TAGTCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCTGAT      NO     TGGT
I : 11  J : 22   :   TAGTCGTGACC      CCAGTGCTGAT      NO     TGGT
I : 11  J : 21   :   TAGTCGTGAC      CAGTGCTGAT      NO     TGGT
I : 11  J : 20   :   TAGTCGTGA      AGTGCTGAT      NO     TGGT
I : 11  J : 19   :   TAGTCGTG      GTGCTGAT      NO     TGGT
I : 11  J : 18   :   TAGTCGT      TGCTGAT      NO     TGGT
I : 11  J : 17   :   TAGTCG      GCTGAT      NO     TGGT
I : 11  J : 16   :   TAGTC      CTGAT      NO     TGGT
I : 11  J : 15   :   TAGT      TGAT      NO     TGGT
I : 11  J : 14   :   TAG      GAT      NO     TGGT
I : 11  J : 13   :   TA      AT      NO     TGGT
I : 11  J : 12   :   T      T      YES     TGGT
I : 12  J : 23   :   AGTCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCTGA      NO     TGGT
I : 12  J : 22   :   AGTCGTGACC      CCAGTGCTGA      NO     TGGT
I : 12  J : 21   :   AGTCGTGAC      CAGTGCTGA      NO     TGGT
I : 12  J : 20   :   AGTCGTGA      AGTGCTGA      NO     TGGT
I : 12  J : 19   :   AGTCGTG      GTGCTGA      NO     TGGT
I : 12  J : 18   :   AGTCGT      TGCTGA      NO     TGGT
I : 12  J : 17   :   AGTCG      GCTGA      NO     TGGT
I : 12  J : 16   :   AGTC      CTGA      NO     TGGT
I : 12  J : 15   :   AGT      TGA      NO     TGGT
I : 12  J : 14   :   AG      GA      NO     TGGT
I : 12  J : 13   :   A      A      YES     TGGT
I : 13  J : 23   :   GTCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 13  J : 22   :   GTCGTGACC      CCAGTGCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 13  J : 21   :   GTCGTGAC      CAGTGCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 13  J : 20   :   GTCGTGA      AGTGCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 13  J : 19   :   GTCGTG      GTGCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 13  J : 18   :   GTCGT      TGCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 13  J : 17   :   GTCG      GCTG      NO     TGGT
I : 13  J : 16   :   GTC      CTG      NO     TGGT
I : 13  J : 15   :   GT      TG      NO     TGGT
I : 13  J : 14   :   G      G      YES     TGGT
I : 14  J : 23   :   TCGTGACCC      CCCAGTGCT      NO     TGGT
I : 14  J : 22   :   TCGTGACC      CCAGTGCT      NO     TGGT
I : 14  J : 21   :   TCGTGAC      CAGTGCT      NO     TGGT
I : 14  J : 20   :   TCGTGA      AGTGCT      NO     TGGT
I : 14  J : 19   :   TCGTG      GTGCT      NO     TGGT
I : 14  J : 18   :   TCGT      TGCT      NO     TGGT
I : 14  J : 17   :   TCG      GCT      NO     TGGT
I : 14  J : 16   :   TC      CT      NO     TGGT
I : 14  J : 15   :   T      T      YES     TGGT
I : 15  J : 23   :   CGTGACCC      CCCAGTGC      NO     TGGT
I : 15  J : 22   :   CGTGACC      CCAGTGC      NO     TGGT
I : 15  J : 21   :   CGTGAC      CAGTGC      NO     TGGT
I : 15  J : 20   :   CGTGA      AGTGC      NO     TGGT
I : 15  J : 19   :   CGTG      GTGC      NO     TGGT
I : 15  J : 18   :   CGT      TGC      NO     TGGT
I : 15  J : 17   :   CG      GC      NO     TGGT
I : 15  J : 16   :   C      C      YES     TGGT
I : 16  J : 23   :   GTGACCC      CCCAGTG      NO     TGGT
I : 16  J : 22   :   GTGACC      CCAGTG      NO     TGGT
I : 16  J : 21   :   GTGAC      CAGTG      NO     TGGT
I : 16  J : 20   :   GTGA      AGTG      NO     TGGT
I : 16  J : 19   :   GTG      GTG      YES     TGGT
I : 16  J : 18   :   GT      TG      NO     TGGT
I : 16  J : 17   :   G      G      YES     TGGT
I : 17  J : 23   :   TGACCC      CCCAGT      NO     TGGT
I : 17  J : 22   :   TGACC      CCAGT      NO     TGGT
I : 17  J : 21   :   TGAC      CAGT      NO     TGGT
I : 17  J : 20   :   TGA      AGT      NO     TGGT
I : 17  J : 19   :   TG      GT      NO     TGGT
I : 17  J : 18   :   T      T      YES     TGGT
I : 18  J : 23   :   GACCC      CCCAG      NO     TGGT
I : 18  J : 22   :   GACC      CCAG      NO     TGGT
I : 18  J : 21   :   GAC      CAG      NO     TGGT
I : 18  J : 20   :   GA      AG      NO     TGGT
I : 18  J : 19   :   G      G      YES     TGGT
I : 19  J : 23   :   ACCC      CCCA      NO     TGGT
I : 19  J : 22   :   ACC      CCA      NO     TGGT
I : 19  J : 21   :   AC      CA      NO     TGGT
I : 19  J : 20   :   A      A      YES     TGGT
I : 20  J : 23   :   CCC      CCC      YES     TGGT
I : 20  J : 22   :   CC      CC      YES     TGGT
I : 20  J : 21   :   C      C      YES     TGGT
I : 21  J : 23   :   CC      CC      YES     TGGT
I : 21  J : 22   :   C      C      YES     TGGT
I : 22  J : 23   :   C      C      YES     TGGT

 Longest Palindrome Substring :  TGGT
```